# Magento 2 Admin Grid per page remove 'Custom' from all Grids

Tags: magento2, grid, pagination

I need to remove the 'Custom' in all Admin Grids. This to avoid a large collection request that probably making website slow.

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/paging/sizes.html
```

I had find it's coming from above mention file. And in a dirty way, I have an option to override this in my admin theme theme and comment out the 'Custom' div.

```
        <div class="selectmenu-item">
            <button
               type="button"
               class="selectmenu-item-action"
               data-bind="
                    click: function () {
                        $data.showCustom()
                            .discardEditing();
                    },
                    visible: !isCustomVisible(),
                    i18n: 'Custom'"></button>
        </div>
```

However it works but still wondering if is there any other nice way to remove it?

Thanks

Comment: did you find any better way to do this?